# Updating JDK/OpenJDK on WSL2 to use with IntelliJ and versions questions

Tags: java, windows-subsystem-for-linux, java-11

I followed IDEA's guide to use WSL2 with IntelliJ and the version that was installed on the WSL was OpenJDK 11.

Since we're about to receive JDK 21, I wonder if there's a more updated version which I should use on this setup.

Also, does the OpenJDK version number correspond with the Oracle JDK version number? Like OpenJDK 11 is equivalent to Oracle JDK 11 and whatsoever.

Thanks!

Comment: What is your distribution in WSL2? Ubuntu, Debian, Arch,...?

Comment: @SimpleJack, it's Ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## This is valid for Ubuntu:

1. Install your Java version of choice (with XX of your preferred version):

`sudo apt install openjdk-XX-jdk-headless`

2. List all your installed version and remember path

`sudo update-alternatives --config java`

3. Change to your version of choice:

`sudo update-java-alternatives --set /path/to/java/version`

Comment: I think you linked a JRE package, but I need a JDK. From using sudo search only openjdk 19 was listed. To put to Java 20 I had to download a tar.gz, unpack, modify .bashrc and use --update-alternatives to register it within the linux terminal. Thanks for the answer anyway!

Comment: Oh shoot, you're right. Corrected this in the answer to **JDK**. And yes, Ubuntu uses Debians package manager. Practically this means, only LTS versions will be available. The next LTS version for Java is version 21 (in a few weeks from now on). So if you want these "short" living versions you have to install them manually.

Answer (score 3):

### Yes, version numbers correspond across Java™ specs, OpenJDK source, JDK products

As for the second part of your Question, “does the OpenJDK version number correspond”… Yes.

[OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) is a project producing source-code.

Several vendors produce [JDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit) binaries/installers based partially or entirely on that code base. Amazon makes *Corretto*, Azul Systems makes *Zulu* and *Zing*, Oracle makes *Oracle JDK* and *GraalVM*, Adoptium at the Eclipse Foundation makes *Temurin*, and so on. See also IBM, Red Hat, BellSoft, Microsoft, SAP, and others.

Fortunately, they  all use the same numbering version.

- Version 21 of all their JDK products implement the [Java SE 21 specifications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/).
- Likewise, OpenJDK source code numbered version 21 implements the same Java SE 21 specifications.

Comment: As I wrote this, I became amazed that I could actually report that these version numbers do indeed correspond. The information technology industry is usually so disorganized, so fractious, and so myopic that mundane yet vital matters such as naming and versioning are either left unattended or botched (looking at you [*USB Implementers Forum*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_Implementers_Forum)). The active, intelligent, and enduring cooperation across the Java community, even between direct competitors, is so rare as to be a wonderful thing to behold.